# Can't sudo because password is disabled

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, passwords, sudo, sudoers

So, in my attempt to prevent the default `ubuntu` user from logging in, and to prevent the default sudo user `me` from logging in with a password, and thus enforcing to use the private key, I managed to lock `me` out, unable to perform any sudo commands.

Here's what happened.

I ran these commands to prevent `ubuntu` from logging in, and to lock `me`'s password.

```
sudo usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin ubuntu
sudo passwd -l me
```

However, I forgot to add `me ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` to the `/etc/sudoers.d/me` beforehand. And now, even though I can still login as `me` with the private key, I can't execute any `sudo`, because it prompts for a password, and the previous password no longer works. I can't login as `ubuntu`, the other sudoer, and so I am basically stuck.

Executing `passwd` as `me` prompts for the current password, which does not exist.

How do I get myself out of this situation?  Do I have terminate this box and reinstall?  This is not happening on my personal box. This is running on AWS.  It's not quite a big of an issue to spin new instances, but I'd like to see if there's an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no other way to change your *own* password without having the current password in the first place. This would have to be done with elevated permissions. But since you don't have them anymore, or cannot get these through `sudo`, a last resort would be to boot into recovery mode and login as the root user. Although I don't think that would be possible for an AWS machine. Same goes for manually writing the sudo configs on the drive, as you don't have the phyisical machine.

Good luck!